# When encoding weights in a neural network as a chromosome in a genetic algorithm, can a binary string be too long to function properly?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I have a feedforward neural network that I want to train using a genetic algorithm.  I have read that the best option is to use a binary string of the weights represented as grey codes.  But in my case, with 65 weights for each chromosome, this would result in a string of length 2080 (65*32 bits).  I understand that this is a complex problem, so it would take longer to reach an optimal solution than having a smaller number of bits in the string, but is 2080 too long for the GA to work at all?  Is there a better way to encode such a large number of weights?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the size of the string would be too much of a problem, but it may be problem-dependent.

If you are worried about the size of the strings, perhaps you could reduce the precision to a lower number of bits per weight and observe the effects that it has on the learning performance.  As you have stated, grey codes are likely best for the representation of the weights.  I've used GA's in other application areas with gene sizes around the same length and have evolved well.

Of course, you would need to ensure that the population size and number of generations is sufficient enough for the problem and fitness function.